# Axlsx in Rails: rendering formula issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, formula, axlsx

When I pass formula to `add_row`, it always returns it with additional sign `'` at the beginning. As result the formula is not calculated but rendered like a text in Excel file.

For example:
Method `sheet_quests.add_row ["=SUM(D7:D8)", "=D7-D8", "=D7"]`
returns

```
'=SUM(D7:D8)  '=D7-D8  '=D7
```

I need to have the result of calculated formula, not a text.

Any ideas?